# Python convert string matrix to float matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to convert the following matrix (string) to float numbers

```
           0                0                0                0                0
            0                0                0                0       78.2949219
   81.0840607       83.2369537   0.000100000005       101.055199       78.5405502
```

i used:

```
import numpy as np
number = []
for line in filename:
    number.append(line)
number = np.array(number)
number_float = number.astype(np.float)
```

but it gives me:
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '         0        0        0        0       0\n'
is that because \n ?

Comment: You need to split the line into separate elements for each number.

Comment: are you trying to read a fulolile? Perhaps `numpy.loadtxt` could be useful?

Comment: thank you! split works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a 2-dimensional matrix, you just have a list of strings, with one element for each line. You need to split it into separate numbers.

```
for line in filename:
    number.append(line.split())
```

You can also do the float conversion at the same time, and you can build the list using a list comprehension.

```
number = [[float(cell) for cell in line] for line in filename]
```

Comment: I think it is better to use list-comprehension instead of `map` (or of course, `list(map(...))`) as `map` returns a map object and not a list (not sure how `np.array` handles map objects)

Comment: @Tomerikoo Always forget that detail about map. I've converted to nested list comprehensions.

Comment: Sorry to be annoying haha but now you just forgot to `split` the `line`